# How to open a description window on the same card when clicked in react/jsx

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs, jsx

I created cards for each product that i am trying to enlist in a page(similar to this https://testhtmlcode.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-01-02.html). Now i am trying to show the long description when clicked on "see more" in the card. In HTML(which i i have tried here: https://testhtmlcode.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-01-02.html) it's worked but in react i am finding it difficult. Can anyone help me here.

React code:

```
CSS:

* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    
    
    .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: left;
      align-items: left;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin: 40px 0;
    }
    
    .container .card {
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
      height: 400px;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
      margin: 20px;
      box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      border-radius: 15px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    }
    
    .container .card .content {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .container .card:hover .content {
      transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    
    .container .card .content .contentBx h2 {
      color: #000000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 20px 0 10px;
      line-height: 1.1em;
    }
    
    .container .card .content .contentBx p {
      color: #000000;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: left;
      margin: 20px 0 10px;
      line-height: 1.1em;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    
    
    .container .card .sci {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50px;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .container .card .sci li {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0 10px;
      transform: translateY(40px);
      transition: 0.5s;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .container .card:hover .sci li {
      transform: translateY(0px);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .container .card .sci li a {
      color: #000000;
      font-size: 20px;
    }



React code:

function App() {
return(
<div>
            <section>
                <div class="container">
                    <!--CARD START-->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="contentBx">
                                <h2>PR1</h2>
                                <p>
                                    PR1 is a health related tracker..
                                    <a data-modal>See more</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="contentBx">
                                <h2>PR1</h2>
                                <p>
                                    PR1 is a health related tracker..
                                    <a data-modal>See more</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>

);
}

export default App;
```

I tried to do the same in html, which worked as expected using a script tag
https://testhtmlcode.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-01-02.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Popoup in javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'system-ui', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: .3s linear 0s all;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.container .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/3747155/pexels-photo-3747155.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .card .content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .card:hover .contentBx {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
.container .card .content .contentBx h2 {
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
.container .card .content .contentBx p {
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.container .card .sci {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.container .card .sci li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.container .card:hover .sci li {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
}
.container .card .sci li a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.blur-filter {
  filter: blur(2px);
}
</style>
<style>
    [modal] {
        opacity: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 120%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        color: white;
        background: #ffffff38;
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: 1s linear 0s all;
    }
    [modal="active"] {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0%;
    }
    [modal] > .modal {
        display: contents;
    }
    [modal] > .flexbox_column {
        margin: 0;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_header {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto 24px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_header > h4 {
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_header > ._close {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 16px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 5px;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: #e2e2e2; 
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: #9a9a9a; 
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #b6b6b6; 
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content > img {
        max-width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        filter: opacity(0.8);
    }
    [data-modal] {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <!--CARD START-->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="contentBx">
                            <h2>PR1</h2>
                            <p>
                                PR1 is a health related tracker..
                                <a data-modal>See more</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <!--MODAL START-->
                        <div modal>
                            <div class="modal flexbox_column">
                                <div class="modal_header"><h4>MEGA DISCOUNT</h4><span onclick="closeModal(this)" class="_close material-symbols-outlined">expand_more</span></div>
                                <div class="modal_content">
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!

                                        Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.

                                        Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!

                                        Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.

                                        Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                    </p>
                                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3756879/pexels-photo-3756879.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Free license from pexels" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--MODAL END-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--CARD END-->
                <!--CARD START-->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="contentBx">
                            <h2>PR1</h2>
                            <p>
                                PR1 is a health related tracker..
                                <a data-modal>See more</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--MODAL START-->
                    <div modal>
                        <div class="modal flexbox_column">
                            <div class="modal_header"><h4>DISCOUNT 50%</h4><span onclick="closeModal(this)" class="_close material-symbols-outlined">expand_more</span></div>
                            <div class="modal_content">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!

                                    Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.

                                    Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!

                                    Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.

                                    Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                </p>
                                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3756879/pexels-photo-3756879.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Free license from pexels" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--MODAL END-->
                </div>
                <!--CARD END-->
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let modalLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-modal]');
    modalLinks.forEach(link => 
        link.addEventListener('click', function() {
            openModal(link)
        })
    );

    function openModal(e) {
        const el = e.closest('.card');
        const modal = el.querySelector('[modal]');
        modal.setAttribute('modal', 'active');
    }

    function closeModal(e) {
        const modal = e.closest('[modal]');
        modal.setAttribute('modal', '');
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to render a array list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to manage state inside your component, in order to do that
here's a basic example of how you can achieve that

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <section>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="card">
              <div className="content">
                <div className="contentBx">
                  {!showMore ? (
                    <>
                      <h2>PR1</h2>
                      <p>
                        PR1 is a health related tracker..
                        <a
                          href="s"
                          onClick={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            setShowMore(true);
                          }}
                        >
                          See more
                        </a>
                      </p>
                    </> :
                    <>
                     // your modal data here
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-brown-fbwfew?file=/src/App.js) for working example. I used the [CSSTransition](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) library for CSS animation purposes. feel free to play and change acording to your preferances

Comment: superb answer. thanks a lot

Comment: Just one more help: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-sutherland-vgkiht. i am showing two links on hover over the card but when i am opening the modal, i dont want to show those two link in the background

Comment: you can't see any links on hover right? Can you recreate the issue on sandbox, so I can take a look and try to fix

Comment: able to open this codesandbox.io/s/recursing-sutherland-vgkiht?

Comment: Ya I can open it, but there's no changes, and I can't see any link on hover when the modal is open inside the card

Comment: my bad. here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-goldstine-p926wu?file=/src/App.js:103-108

Comment: I added a config file for the list of products and trying to use that to map in app.js.. at that time it is not working. updated the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-sutherland-vgkiht?file=/src/App.js

Comment: refer to this https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-forest-vbpqm8 I made the changes

Comment: thank you very much.. chrome seems to be working but in firefox, css breaks

Comment: it's because of browser engine changes, you may find a workaround if you search for the exact issue in the internet

Comment: the modal position creates issue.. I will try to find the solution though. one more small help. sorry to ask many times but this is the first time trying something in front end. I want to display description when ever clicked on show more and i want to close the description card only when use clicks on close symbol. Currently user can open a single card description. this might require a small logic change, if you can help, would be greatfull

Comment: ya, currently we have only saved one id in the state, you can make it an array, and you can check if the id of the card includes in the array and keep, when the user click close, you can remove the item from the state array

Comment: I updated this https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-forest-vbpqm8

Comment: thanks.. when more than 3 cards are selected,, if we close the first, there some css issue is happening

Comment: it may not relate to the JS side, check with style layer specifically